# Magento 2 : Products not showing on front store due to re-index issue

Tags: magento2, reindex, product-reindexing, store-front

There are no products showing on store front. After routine health checkup of the store, below error found during the reindex:

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`

**Cluster_block_exception [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/Disk Usage Exceeded Flood-Stage Watermark, Index Has Read-Only-Allow-Delete Block]**

Answer (score 1):

Folks, during further debugging found that, '*This error occurred when the Elasticsearch feels that the disk is running low on space so it puts itself into read-only mode.*'

To solve the issue, I followed below steps and it go resolved:

- Step 1 : Go to your root project in command line
- Step 2 : Run below mentioned command

  curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'
- Step 3 : After running above command successfully, run below mentioned command:

  curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
- Step 4 : After running above codes, run below mentioned commands

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
> php bin/magento cache:clean

After the above 4 simple steps, issue has been resolved at my end.

Answer (score 0):

As this site suggest : [Meetanshi - Solve ‘cluster block exception’](https://meetanshi.com/blog/cluster-block-exception-in-magento-2/)

The “disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark” error while reindexing in Magento 2 can be solved by disabling the cluster routing allocation disk threshold. You can follow the steps mentioned below to solve the ‘cluster block exception’ in Magento 2:

You can try to do these steps :

### Step 1

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'
```

### Step 2

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

In addition, you can also run the following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

hope it work for you